# nilpotent transformation properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I search for a proof for the following theorem but I did not find.

I will appreciate a lot if anyone will direct me to a proof or something.

Let $V$ be a vector space

Let $N$ be a nilpotent matrix.

The minimal polynomial for $N$ is $X^{k}$ for some positive integer k ≤ n.

How do I prove that

$\exists v \in V$ such that {$v,N(v),...,N^{k-1}(v)$} 
is linear independent.

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take $v$ so that $N^{k-1}(v)\not = 0$.

Hint 1: Suppose you have $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha _{k-1}, \sum\limits_0^{k-1}\alpha_iN^i(v)=0$

Hint 2:

> Apply $N^j$ to that relation

Hint 3:

> If you apply $N^{k-1}$, you get $\alpha_{0}N^{k-1}(v)=0$ so $\alpha_0=0$
>
>  If you apply $N^{k-2}$, you get $\alpha_1N^{k-1}(v)+\alpha_0N^{k-2}(v)=0$ from which you get $\alpha_1=0$
>
>  Now just do a recurrence (the line just above that one isn't needed, it's just here to show you how it'll go).

Answer (score 1):

If the operator $1,N, N^{2},\ldots, N^{k-1}$ are linearly dependent then let the non-trivial dependence relation be $\sum_{0 \leq i \leq k-1} a_{i}N^{i} = 0$. Then clearly $p(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{i}x^{i}$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial which contradicts your data.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29 for any reference.