# is there a matrix that follows the requirements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a 3 x 3 matrix , name it $A$, 
that 
$$A^4 = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0& 0& 1\\
0& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& 0 \end{array}\right).
$$

*sorry I just don't know how to insert math form here because I'm new

Comment: I added some TeX-code. Please check that it is the way you want to see it. It takes a while to get the hang of arrays (a tad more to learn that typesetting more basic formulas), but you can learn by studying the examples. Feel free to ask, if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your equation implies that zero is the only eigenvalue of $A$. Then thinking about the Jordan canonical form you quickly see that you must have $A^3=0$, which gives you a contradiction.

---

Without JCF (or characteristic vs. minimal polynomials) one way would be as follows.
Clearly $A^8=0$ (=all zeros matrix). I claim that for $3\times3$ matrices this implies that already $A^3=0$. Assume contrariwise that $A^3x\neq0$ for some vector $x$. Let $n$ be the lowest exponent such that $A^nx=0$. From $A^8=0$ we know that such an exponent exists, and $n\le 8$.

Here's an exercise. Show that the vectors $x_0=x$, $x_1=Ax$, $x_2=A^2x$,$\ldots,$
$x_{n-1}=A^{n-1}x$ are then linearly independent.

**Hint:** Assume a relation of linear dependence. Multiply it by powers of $A$.

After that can you conclude that we must have $n\le 3$?

Comment: Can you explain please how to prove it without Jordan? haven't learned it yet so i'm not suppose to use it

Comment: Ok, @user84636. I added extended hints for a solution that does not depend on JCF, characteristic polynomials and such. Left a couple steps for you to chew on!

Comment: And ask for more help, if you get stuck with any of the steps :-)

Comment: Or [take a peek](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440244/11619) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ then $\lambda^p$ is an eigenvalue of $A^p$.

Now suppose that $A$ exists so since $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A^4$ then $0$ is also the only eigenvalue of $A$, thus $A$ is a nilpotent matrix and then its characteristic polynomial is $x^3$ hence by Cayley Hamilton theorem we have $A^3=A^4=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: Although it probably answers OP's question, this is only true if $A$ is triangularisable in some space, right?

Comment: Clearly my answer is true in $\mathbb C$ but it remains true  in any field, just think to its algebraic closure.